# "Text-decoration: none" no me está funcionando por más que lo intento

Tags: html, css, nav, text-color

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de práctica, y todo hasta ahora me está resultando bien, pero cuando comencé a utilizar una etiqueta ul se me imposibilitó cambiar tanto el text-decoration como el color de un .

Intenté de todo, como usar !important y cambiar clases, pero nada. También he intentado aplicar algunas de las soluciones que aparecen en este mismo foro.

```css
* {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.toolkit-bar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: rgb(142, 142, 243);
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.toolkit-bar__text {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    left: 60px;
    font-weight: 100px;
}

.toolkit-bar__icons {
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-bottom: -10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-weight: 90px;
    width: 50px;
}

.toolkit-bar__icons a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.toolkit-bar__icons:hover {
    color: blue;
}

.toolkit-bar i {
    max-width: 200px;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: rgb(253, 208, 234);
    box-shadow: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.nav__container-logo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.nav__logo {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav__logo img {
    width: 7%;
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
    top: 46px;
    border-bottom: none;
    z-index: 100;
}

.nav__buttons {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0px;
    bottom: 2px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 75px;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.nav__buttons-item {
    display: inline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: rgb(248, 195, 231);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100px;
    border-left: 30px solid rgb(248, 195, 231);
    border-right: 30px solid rgb(248, 195, 231);
}

.nav__buttons-item {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Abrazo de Oso | Inicio</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="resources/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/toolkit-nav.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/normalize.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4a3c81f854.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="toolkit-bar">
            <p class="toolkit-bar__text toolkitbar__content">¡Visita nuestras redes sociales!</p>
            <div class="toolkit-bar__icons toolkit-bar__content"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/abrazodeoso.peluches/" target="_BLANK"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></div>
            <div class="toolkit-bar__icons toolkit-bar__content"><a href="https://m.facebook.com/100083547669607/" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa-brands fa-square-facebook"></i></a></div>
            <div class="toolkit-bar__icons toolkit-bar__content"><a href="https://wa.me/+56984460812" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i></a></div>
        </div>
        <nav class="nav">
            <div class="nav__container-logo">
                <div class="nav__logo">
                <img src="resources/logo.png" alt="Logo">
            </div>
            <div class="nav__buttons">
                <ul>
                    <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-categorias"><a href="#">Categorías</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-contacto"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-informacion"><a href="#">Información</a></li>
                    <li class="nav__buttons-item nav__item-tendencia"><a href="#">Tendencias</a></li>
                </ul>     
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Cabe recalcar que también estoy utilizando normalize, no sé si influya. Si hay alguna otra corrección que quisieran darle a mi código (especialmente css) háganmelo saber, estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: Lo que quieres es quitar ese borde color azul debajo de cada botón?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La propiedad `text-decoration` está funcionando correctamente, la línea azul que sale bajo cada uno de tus enlaces se debe a la propiedad `border-bottom: 1px solid blue;` definida en la clase `.nav__buttons-item`. Eliminando esta propiedad, la línea dejará de aparecer.